# Why is "cementerio" spelled with "n"?

Tags: etimología, historia, ortografía, pronunciación, latín

I am aware that *cementerio* has nothing to do with *cemento*. It comes from Latin *coemeterium* which comes from Greek κοιμητήριον, *koimeterion* = sleeping place, bedroom, dormitory.

I have not found any plausible explanation for the occurrence of the *n* in the Spanish (and Catalan) spelling. Where does it come from? **Is there a more general tendency in Spanish to insert *n* while adopting Latin words**, or is *cementerio* the only instance?

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?cementerio (the entries authored by the mysterious "Helena" are usually trustable :) ) says (emphasis by me) that

> ... **jamás en la Edad Media las tumbas se cementaban**. La forma además alterna con cimenterio **desde antiguo**. La gente era enterrada directamente en la tierra y los nobles y reyes en pétreos sarcófagos. **Nadie ha estudiado realmente a qué se debe esa forma con la nasal**.

So the influence of *cemento* to the spelling and pronunciation of *cementerio* is not plausible. However, I know that sometimes just a *sound* similarity of words might influence an alteration of one of them so I am still open to this option.

Comment: This "n" is seen in some other romance languages e.g. Asturian *cementeriu*, Catalan *cementiri*, Occitan *cementèri *, Picard *chimintière*, Walloon *cimintire*, Ligurian *çementeri* (as well as Polish *cmentarz*).

Comment: @jacobo Thanks for the Polish *cmentarz* - I knew the word but I had never realized that it's a cognate with *cemetery* and *cementerio* :)

Comment: Galician has no n as we use "cemiterio": https://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/busca/cemiterio but I don't know if it is a neologism adapted from spanish. We also use "camposanto".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spanish etymologist Corominas states that the origin of that middle *-n-* is due mostly to a prolongation of the nasalization produced by the previous *-m-*. He also states that the word could have been influenced by Latin *caementum* (Spanish 'cimiento', 'cemento') just by the similarity of how both words sound, but that cannot have been the only reason.

Note that you can find *cimenterio*, *cimeterio* and *cemeterio* in Spanish texts from the 15th to 17th centuries, maybe emphasizing the influence of *cimiento*. Quevedo used *cimenterio* in his works, while *cimeterio* and *cemeterio* were quite less used, but still used in the *Diálogos familiares de la agricultura cristiana* (1589) by Juan de Pineda as Corominas states.

As I have researched, that prolongation of the nasalization may not be something exclusive of the word *cementerio*. It also seems to appear in other words:

- *[Remanso](https://dle.rae.es/remanso)* comes from Latin *remansum*, and this from *remanēre*. In this case, the added *-n-* already happened in Latin, but still it can be considered a prolongation of the nasalization of the previous *-m-*.
- *[Ninguno](https://dle.rae.es/ninguno)* comes from Latin *nec unus* (Spanish 'ni uno'). Again, the added *-n-* can be a prolongation of the nasalization of the initial *n-*. In fact, there was an intermediate form *neguno* (and therefore *nenguno*), according to Corominas. Note also that in this case, the added *-n-* could have also been influenced by the *[nin](https://dle.rae.es/nin)* version of Spanish *ni*. But even so, *nin* itself can be considered as having a prolongation of the nasalization of the initial *n-* (or influenced by Latin *non*, but again...).

There are other cases of an extra *-n-* added to a word, but those are usually explained by contamination from other words, such as *[alondra](https://dle.rae.es/alondra)*, from Latin *alaudŭla*, probably influenced by *golondrina* (from Latin *hirundo, -ĭnis*). Both words refer to a kind of bird.

Comment: "Prolongation of nasalization" - like once the nose comes into action in the sound production, it does not want to give up so easy? :) Is there anything like this also in English?

Comment: @HonzaZidek that could be a good question for the [English.SE] site. :-)

Comment: Aquí tienes: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/566839/73094 :)

Comment: Can you provide a link to Corominas' works, please?

Comment: @TheDarkSide unfortunately, Corominas' works are not in the public domain nor have been published for consulting on any web site.